# Как добавить Node.JS к редакторам и IDE?

Tags: node.js, cmd, webstorm, консоль

Я могу ввести команду `node -v` в `cmd.exe`, а вот в других программах (VS Code/WebStorm) не работает это. Вот в чём проблема: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: перезапустите webstorm либо перезагрузите пк

Comment: Ты кстати как ноду устанавливал? Если чё - у них через msi-установщик всё начинает и так работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убедитесь, что путь к `node` есть в системной переменной `%PATH%` (https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10).
После изменения `%PATH%`, перезапустите Webstorm (VSCode); если не поможет, перезагрузите компьютер